# RxJS: Observable.create() vs. Observable.from()

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

What's the difference between these two?

```
return Observable.create(function(observer) {
    if (array)
        observer.next([]);
    else
        observer.next(null);
    observer.complete();
});
```

and

```
return Observable.from( array ? [] : null );
```

I thought it could be the same but didn't work the same.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `create(...)` is a generic `Observable` factory method for creating an `Observable` in which you will explicitly dictate how values are passed to the `Subscriber`

For instance, if you were to create a timer base `Observable` (don't it already exists as `Observable.timer`) you could do:

```
   Observable.create(observer => {
     const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
       observer.next(0);
       observer.complete();
     }, 500);

     return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
   });
```

The `from(...)` is what I call a *conformance* operator in that it attempts to coerce a passed in data type into an `Observable` (make it conform). This means that it will accept a variety of types and convert them into `Observables`. These types include:

- Arrays
- Promises
- Generators
- Observable-like things

There are specific converters as well that you can find such as `fromArray` and `fromPromise` which specifically convert those types, but `from` more of a swiss-army knife of those methods

If you just need a single value you should be using `Observable.of` (the docs appear to be out of date, `just/return` was renamed to `of` in RxJS 5 and I don't think they are aliased anymore).

i.e.

```
// Don't quote me on the import part
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

Observable.of(1, 2, 3, 4).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1):

One difference is: `Observable.from()` specifically forbids `null` as something it accepts. So the first is kind of a workaround to create an observable returning `null`. (See the accepted answer for the main difference though.)

Better (shorter) way would be to use [just](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/just.html):

```
return Observable.just( array ? [] : null );
```

But I couldn't find where to get it or how to import it.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/just';
```

This isn't present in my distribution of rxjs.
*Edit:* `just` was renamed to `of`, see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you are returning an array, the difference is that 'create/next' will emit the whole array at once but 'from' will emit each item as many times as its length, so to subscriber,

`Observable.create(observer => observer.next(myArray))` will fire onNext event once to return myArray whereas `Observable.from(myArray)` will emit many onNext events to return one item each time.

Answer (score 1):

**Observable.from():**

You have a list of values (that has nothing to do with Rx) and an Observable is created **from** this list. When an Observer subscribe to this Observable, the list of values are passed as Next() events one by one then Completed() is eventually passed and you cannot control this process.

**Observable.create():**

You create the sequence of event by explicitly emitting the events one by one. Hence, you can emit OnCompleted and OnError events whenever you want